# Single-page-application with HTMX, URL browsing history and manual reloading of a page

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, html5-history, htmx

I have an application with fixed header and footer (it is important that they are not reloaded when we navigate through pages). I use HTMX. The attribute `hx-push-url` allows to have browsing history through the pages: we can use the "back" and "forward" buttons, and it works as expected:

`index.html`:

```
<style>
#header { background-color: yellow; height: 20%; }
#container { background-color: gray; height: 60%; }
#footer { background-color: yellow; height: 20%; }
</style>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.7.0"></script>
<div id="header">This is the header</div>
<div id="container">
This is the main container
<button hx-get="newpage1" hx-target="#container" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-push-url="true">Go to newpage1</button>
</div>
<div id="footer">This is the footer</div>
```

`newpage1`:

```
<div id="container">Hello
<button hx-get="newpage2" hx-target="#container" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-push-url="true">Go to newpage2</button>
</div>
```

`newpage2`:

```
<div id="container">Test</div>
```

After having clicked on "Go to newpage1" button, the container div is replaced by the content of `newpage1` as expected and the browser URL is now `http://127.0.0.1/newpage1`.

Problem: if we enter this URL *directly* in the browser, we won't have the full page, but only the container `<div id="container">...</div>`.

**What is the common HTMX solution to this problem when we build a single page application?**

Comment: https://github.com/sponsfreixes/jinja2-fragments should do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, check the Request Headers for the [HX-Request](https://htmx.org/reference/#request_headers)
header, and if it exists, then just send your partial, otherwise send the full page.

If you are using Django on the server side, this method is explained step by step [in this part](https://juliensalinas.com/en/htmx-intercoolerjs-django-nlpcloud/#allow-manual-page-reloading) of a blog article:

> The problem with the above is that if a user manually reloads the token or the support page, he will only end up with the HTML fragment instead of the whole HTML page.
> The solution, on the Django side, is to render 2 different templates depending on whether the request is coming from htmx or not. Here is how you could do it. In your views.py you need to check whether the HTTP_HX_REQUEST header was passed in the request. If it was, it means this is a request from htmx and in that case you can show the HTML fragment only. If it was not, you need to render the full page.

Comment: Isn't there a general HTMX solution which doesn't require to do this manually? I would like to avoid to manually create a full page for `newpage1` by taking header + content of `newpage1` + footer. Doesn't HTMX provide a generic solution to this single-page-application pattern?

Comment: Not sure what you're running server side.. I use ASP.NET Core on the server side, so on the clientside I can define which server side handler will be called, but in this case it ends up being a querystring so that may not help your situation. Since these are all GET requests, not sure how else the server would know to only send the partial or send the full page unless your checking some condition like a header or perhaps a querystring ... if you enter the address in the browser and go there, I would think that is basically a request for the full page.

Comment: Thanks @pthomson. Isn't there a solution in which the server always sends header + empty container div + footer, and then let the container content be filled with AJAX on pageload? I'm trying to understand how this would work with HTMX. (or if I need to code this manually).

Comment: when you say " if we enter this URL directly in the browser" are you talking about entering the URL `http://127.0.0.1/index.html` ? Can you have newpage2 check for the HX-Request header and if it does NOT exist, then redirect to newpage1 ?

Comment: I mean entering `http://127.0.0.1/newpage1` in the browser URL bar: then only the fragment `<div id="container">...</div>` would be served, instead of the full page. So yes your idea would work (I could check in my backend if the request header for HTMX is present or not, and based on this, I could serve full vs only-div content), but I wanted to avoid to reinvent the wheel, and use the full power of HTMX library to avoid doing such things manually. Perhaps HTMX has a Single-page-application example, that shows the best practice in HTMX?

Comment: I think of HTMX an alternative to a SPA framework. Lets your server side application feel like a SPA. Here is an article regarding HTMX vs SPA https://htmx.org/essays/spa-alternative/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246283/discussion-between-pthomson-and-basj).